# How to make this kind of view in xml android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

What views could I use in Android Studio to make this view on my app?

[image]

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `TabLayout` in android

But android provides very basic design of `TabLayout`, you have to customize the design according to your needs

https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/
https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-create-custom-tab-layout-in-android-android-studio-java-83e87eb837ad